# Basic custom module installation error - "...Controller does not exist in ReflectionMethod"

Tags: 8

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/my-first-drupal-8-module) to create an most simple custom module.

I have created files inside `/modules/elevator_search`:

[image]

And in the `/src/Controller` I've placed:
[image]

The `/modules/elevator_search/evelator_search.info.yml`:

```
name: Elevator Search
description: Moduł wyszukiwarki wind
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
```

The `/modules/elevator_search/evelator_search.module` is empty.

The `/modules/elevator_search/evelator_search.routing.yml`:

```
elevator_search.content:
  path: '/elevator_search'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\elevator_search\Controller\EvelatorController::content'
    _title: 'Hello world'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

The `/modules/elevator_search/src/Controller/ElevatorController.php`:

```
<?php
/**
@file
Contains \Drupal\elevator_search\Controller\ElevatorController.
 */

namespace Drupal\elevator_search\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class EvelatorController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {
      return array(
          //'#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => t('Hello world'),
        );
  }
};
```

It did show up under /admin/modules:
[image]

But when I try to install it I get an error:

> ReflectionException: Class Drupal\elevator_search\Controller\EvelatorController does not exist in ReflectionMethod->__construct() (line 123 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class' name is "EvelatorController", the name of the php file of the class is "ElevatorController.php" - it is just a spelling problem